# How to remove a added site module in sitecore 9.0.1

Tags: sxa

I am using sitecore 9.0.1 with sxa 1.7. I have created a module by cloning existing components and added to my site .I want to remove the added module and unclone the cloned rendering how can i do that .
Is it possible to remove without deleting the items manually.

Thanks

Comment: I am not aware of any existing feature up to 10.1 to do that. If you added the feature locally you can rollback the commits in source control.

Comment: You need to do it manually unfortunatelly

Comment: you have to create anti-package before you add the package

Comment: @MichaelWest Correct, there is no such script.

Answer (score 0):

There is no script available out of the box in SXA to remove the installed module. You need to do this manually or you can write Sitecore PowerShell script on your own to remove a module (if you need to remove the installed module frequently).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way you can undo that, and only you can do manually, but i have some suggestions you can try which i did

1. You can search for that package so for instance, i cloned one rendering "Free Hand HTML" and also cloned one component called "Plain HTML" and created my own module called "Free Hand"
2. Now if after doing all these, basically it creates templates, renderings, branch templates, Media library folders etc, so there are multiple reference to it
3. You can simply search for your module in sitecore search, you will find all places in the content tree, go and remove them manually

Thanks,
D