# Uninstall SXA Module from the created Site

Tags: sxa

I am using Sitecore 10 Update 1, I have created a new SXA tenant and Site that is installed with all SXA modules, i want to un install some modules from this site.

Is there a way to remove the module with all its components?

Comment: Which particular module would you like to remove?

Comment: There is no OOTB feature to uninstall SXA modules

Comment: This was also answered in the question https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/28113/how-to-remove-a-added-site-module-in-sitecore-9-0-1